# Using system command in Perl for using gzip

Tags: perl, compression

I have some zipped files (.gz format) and I want to automate that process.Here is what I have:

```
    !# /usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;

    my $input1 = $ARGV[0];
    my $unzip_command = 'gzip -d $input1';
    system $unzip_command;
```

I'm getting an error that asks to use -f to force decompression (tried it, just hangs). Can you spot where my syntax went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40411269/5830574) you have to use **double quotes** for the `$input1` to get interpolated (expanded).

#### But

your script is **vulnerable to code-injection**. Consider this case (assuming your script's name is `decompress.pl`):

```
$ ./decompress.pl "foo.gz; rm -rf /"
```

This will finally execute

```
gzip -d foo.gz; rm -rf /
```

Please read about the two modes [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) can be called in: either with a string (which is then interpreted by your shell) or with an array of arguments (which bypasses the shell and its interpretation).

Better would be to use the array-mode here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input1 = $ARGV[0];
my @unzip_command = ('gzip', '-d', $input1);
system( @unzip_command );
```

(Btw: you had a typo in your she-bang line. It's not `!#/usr/bin/perl` but `#!…`. Please *paste* your code instead of re-typing it to avoid typos.)

Comment: Good point. Also fails if the filename contains any spaces or shell meta characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes when you want a variable to be interpolated.

```
my $unzip_command = "gzip -d $input1";
```

Otherwise you will be executing the command 'gzip -d $input1' rather than 'gzip -d myfile.gz'.

In this case, system is passing your command to the shell, which is interpreting $input1 as a shell variable. Of course that does not exist.